# Fire Tag in Google Tag Manager on url change of React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

I have added Google Tag Manager to my React Application with the help of this module - [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module)

So i initialized my GTM on base file as the doc says

```
  const tagManagerArgs = {
    gtmId: process.env.REACT_APP_GTM_KEY,
  };
  TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);

//This code only executes the first time when the site loads, not on every route change
```

and i see the script tag in my  tag

```
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX&gtm_auth=&gtm_preview=&gtm_cookies_win=x"></script>
```

So as soons as i open my website i see **container load** in the debug mode of GTM and see the tag GA - UA-XXXXXXX - All Pages fired properly.

Now i have a button in my home page which on clicking takes me to the new route, so in debug mode i see history change but I want to fire GA - UA-XXXXXXX - All Pages Tag in that history change, which doesn't happen. This tag only gets fired when i refresh the website on any of the routes

Comment: did you 
"Set a History Change trigger in your Tag Manager container"?

Comment: thank you so much for this, saved my day ! also do you the reason when does gtmlinkClick gets fired? i am in react-router but on history.push- gtmlinkClick doesnot fires :(

Comment: can you share code snippet for this? also, if my above suggestions helped do upvote :)